# How to disable a constraint in Oracle with select statement as constraint name

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I try to disable a constraint attached to a column in a table

```
ALTER TABLE
   ADV_TEST_COURSE_CREDIT
DISABLE constraint

name = (SELECT 
    constraint_name
from
    user_constraints natural join 
    user_cons_columns
where 
    table_name = 'ADV_TEST_COURSE_CREDIT' AND 
    column_name = 'SEQUENCE_NUMBER' AND
    constraint_type = 'C');
```

I try the statement above. It is not working. Any idea on how to make it work.

Table `ADV_TEST_COURSE_CREDIT` exists in dev, UAT, Production, so the constraint name is different, but it is all attached a column called `SEQUENCE_NUMBER`

Comment: You're mixing up DDL and DML and it's not going to work that way.  You need to use Dynamic SQL in a PL/SQL block

Answer (score 3):

You need dynamic sql and some plsql:

```
declare name varchar2(200);
begin
SELECT 
    constraint_name
into name
from
    user_constraints natural join 
    user_cons_columns
where 
    table_name = 'ADV_TEST_COURSE_CREDIT' AND 
    column_name = 'SEQUENCE_NUMBER' AND
    constraint_type = 'C');
execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE  ADV_TEST_COURSE_CREDIT DISABLE CONSTRAINT :1' using name;
end;
```

Comment: It would surprise me if you could use bind variables i.e. `USING ...` in such statement.

Comment: execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE  ADV_TEST_COURSE_CREDIT DISABLE :1' using name; I have issue with the substitution. Error report -
ORA-06550: line 12, column 26:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Change the last line to:

execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE  ADV_TEST_COURSE_CREDIT DISABLE CONSTRAINT '||name;

Comment: Yeah, sorry. But Rene already showed the fix. I'll correct it.